# Odoo 8 - get products many2many attribute id (taxes_id) in python

Tags: python, odoo-8

I am trying to get the `taxes_id` from a product template which is a many2many attribute field.
I think I somehow need to read an array?

Can anyone point me in the right direction how to read the id?

My tests are:

```
bla = self.pool.get('product.template').browse(cr, uid, id, context)
bla.taxes_id
```

But it's not working...

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

```
taxes = self.pool.get('product.template').browse(cr, uid, id, context)
if taxes and taxes.taxes_id:
    for tax in taxes.taxes_id:
        print tax.name
        ### tax.id
```

taxes_id is not required field in product.template it may not have values, you should provide checking for value existance.